# What happens to our existing Apps after the release of v2.0 of Facebook's API?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-apps, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

Facebook has launched their new app API recently, what happens to all the apps developed before that? We noticed one of our App stopped working, was this caused by Facebook changing their API? thanks

Comment: I would recommend contacting the Facebook support.

Answer (score 1):

Old apps can continue to use Version 1.0 of the API until 2015-04-30. You can find a lot more info on what changed and how to upgrade on:

1. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog/
2. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading/